# como podria colocar un slider dentro de otro slider usando bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, angular

Estoy usando bootstrap y angular, voy poco a poco tratando de resolver cada problema. ahorita estoy tratando de usar un carusel dentro de un modal y este modal esta dentro de otro carusel. el problema es que cuando inserto el carusel dentro del modal el primer carusel que esta fuera (el general por decirlo así) se descontrola, cuando hago click para pasar al siguiente item se desaparecen las imagenes. le cambie los id a los caruseles para que no generarn conflicto y el problema sigue, que pudiera ser? aquí esta el codigo del carusel general:

```html
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div> <span class="text-hot">
          <b>HOT</b> </span> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="text-hot align-middle">
              list
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--<div *ngIf="inmuebles!=null; else espera">-->
  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z].id}}_{{inmuebles[z].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio: {{inmuebles[i].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].nombre}}</h1> -->
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+1].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}</h1>
              <div class="card-body">

                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+1].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+2].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+2].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+2].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+3].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+3].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+3].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+4].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+4].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+4].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+5].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+5].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+5].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+5].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--</div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>-->
</div>
```

y este es el modal donde tengo el otro carusel:

```html
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="" id="cont-descripcion">
        <p class="text-center">Descripcion</p>
      </div>

      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bath fa-2x "></i> <p> Baños: 1 <p> </td>
            <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bed fa-2x"></i> <p> Recamaras: 2 <p> </td>
            <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-ruler fa-2x "></i> <br/> 100</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es interesante, puedes crear un [ejemplo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?